# Angular js: different approach to declare variable inside controller

Tags: angularjs

learning angular so apologized that some time asking wired question when i stuck to understand.

### see a sample code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.op1= '';
    this.op2='';
    var op3='';
});
```

now tell me what would be difference between this two `$scope.op1= ''; and this.op2='';` ?

please guide me. thanks

Comment: You should review [the ngController documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) and pay attention to the 'Controller as' syntax.

Comment: i check the link still the issue is not clear. so anyone can help me to understand please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code, that can explain the difference when we use $scope and this in constroller. var any ways will create local varibles with no access from html.
See the code to understand.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.op1= 'op1';
    this.op2='op2';
    var op3='';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" >
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as a">
    op1  : {{a.op1 ||'invalid'}}<br/>
    op2 : {{a.op2 ||'invalid'}}<br/>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    op1  : {{op1 ||'invalid'}}<br/>
    op2 : {{op2 ||'invalid'}}<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whatever i understand from your code that if we declare anything in controller with this keyword then it will be the property of controller instance but when declare variable or function with $scope keyword then it will be property of $scope object not instance object. am i right?

Comment: what is the meaning of this code `myCtrl as a` when we work with $scope then we do not have to declare any alias but controller instance is created then too. help me to understand this.

Comment: when you do not use a alias, $scope will give you an object to share/link variable between your HTML and JS. But if you use alias, you don't need $scope to share/link variables in HTML and JS. Using any of the two method is fine and will not affect on your outcome. I personally prefer $scope